# How to do a th:if statement in thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

How can I do a th:if statement to match 2 expressions?

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" th:object="${server}" th:action="@{/addServer}" method="POST">
     <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>

    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Host:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
       <input type="text" style="width: 500px" class="form-control" th:field="*{host}"/>
</div>
</div>
</form>

<!----------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<tr th:object="${test}">
    <td th:text ="${test.Status}"></td>
     <td th:text="${test.host}"></td>
    <td th:text="${test.version}"></td>
</tr>
```

How can I check if test.host is = to th:field="*host"? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*{host}` is the same as `${server.host}` (because server is your form's th:object).  To compare it with something else you can use that same expression.  Something like:

```
th:if="${server.host == test.host}"
```

EDIT:
does this do what you want?

```
<table>
  <tr th:each="t: ${test}" th:if="${server.host == t.host}">
    <td th:text="${t.Status}" />
    <td th:text="${t.host}" />
    <td th:text="${t.version}" />
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Compiler cant find server.host. In different div tag would cause this problem?

Comment: It's all about scope... Where is `${server}` defined in your thymeleaf?  If it's on the model, you should be able to access it in any tag.  If you've defined it somewhere else, you'll have to use that same expression.

Comment: I got it, but it's not working the way I wanted it to work. It worked when I used index[x] to specify a host. I wanted it to iterate through the whole list. If test.host matches server.host. I don't want to specify an index[x]

Comment: Thank you, the edit example is exactly what I needed!