# Showing default image Thymleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I want to show background image in thymleaf when image exist but if that does not exist i want to show default image there. What i tried is below

```
<div class="reward-header"
 th:attrappend="style='background-image:url('+ ${rewardCampaign.image != null ? 
 rewardCampaign.image : '' } + ')'  ">
```

In the last empty quote i want to put a default image like this

```
<div class="reward-header"
 th:attrappend="style='background-image:url('+ ${rewardCampaign.image != null ? 
 rewardCampaign.image : @{/assets/img/samp-img-1.jpg} } + ')'  ">
```

but its showing error.what is the right syntax?

Comment: Using two divs - one with `th:if` and the other with `th:unless` - may be less cumbersome, here (a matter of opinion). There are examples in various SO questions, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620438/how-to-do-a-thif-statement-in-thymeleaf); and also in [the documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#simple-conditionals-if-and-unless).

Answer (score 1):

try with below snippet

```
<div class="reward-header" th:with="imageUrl=${rewardCampaign.image} ?  
   ${rewardCampaign.image } : @{'/assets/img/samp-img-1.jpg'}"  
    th:style="'background-image:url('+${imageUrl}+')'">
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
<div  th:with="image=${rewardCampaign.image} ?: @{/assets/img/samp-img-1.jpg}"
      th:style="|background-image: url('${image}')|"
      class="reward-header">
```