# Make <p> appear and dissapear in Thymeleaf according to variable

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

Hello I am building an application in Spring Boot and Thymeleaf and I have a paragraph that I want to make it appear only if it has a value. If it does not I do not want it to appear.

Here is the code that I have tried:

```
<h2 th:text="'Raspuns: ' + ${raspuns}" th:disabled="${raspuns}==null"></h2>
```

But when I enter the page it says: Raspuns: null I want to make that dissapear.

Comment: There is no `<p>` element in the code fragment in the question. What exactly is it that you want to show/hide, here? The `<h2>` element, or something else?

Comment: Maybe you just want to use a Thymeleaf `if` statement:  `<h2 th:if="${raspuns} != null" th:text="'Raspuns: ' + ${raspuns}"></h2>`.  [How to do a th:if statement in thymeleaf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620438/how-to-do-a-thif-statement-in-thymeleaf)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`<h2 th:if="${raspuns} != null" th:text="'Raspuns: ' + ${raspuns}"></h2>`

see more about conditions in the documentation:

[Thymeleaf Conditional Evaluation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#conditional-evaluation)

Comment: Thanks @andrewJames , I added that reference.